# How to move an item from one observable array to another?

Tags: knockout.js

In knockout.js I have a list that is mapped based on name:

```
firstList: [{name: 'derp'}, {name: 'tom'}, {name: 'derpina'}]
secondList: []
```

I want to remove the object based on name from one list to another. I can remove the item simply using:

```
firstList.mappedRemove({ name: 'derp' });
```

So how can I first copy the information before removing it into another list such that the result is as follows:

```
firstList : [{name: 'tom'}, {name: 'derpina'}]
secondList: [{name: 'derp'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation the `.mappedRemove()` function is functionally equivalent to the regular `ko.observableArray` functions.

`myObservableArray.remove(...)` removes the specified items and returns them as an array. I would assume that the `.mappedRemove()` function does the same.